# Template literal with super in ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use super() inside template literal in my class, here's the super class code:

```
class Person{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    get name(){
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(newVal){
        this._name = newVal;
    }

    doWork(){
        return `${this.name} is coming from person` ;
    }
}
```

and this is the child class:

```
class Employee extends Person{
constructor(name, title){
    super(name);
    this.title = title;
}

get title(){
    return this._title;
}

set title(newVal){
    this._title = newVal;
}

doWork(){

    console.log(this.name);
    return  `${super()} ${this.name}`; //here is my issue
    }
  }
```

I am trying to reference the doWork function in the Person class inside the child class while using template literals, but it's not allowing me, I have this in console:

*'super' keyword unexpected here*

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The `super` keyword is only valid under very specific circumstances. All of those circumstances are listed in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).

Comment: If someone answered your question, click the empty checkmark next to it to mark it as correct. Otherwise, refine the question.

Answer (score 2):

You want `super.doWork()`, not `super()`